# how to solve single loop complexity ,when the condition is dependent on some other variable?

Tags: time-complexity

What is the time complexity for this code:

```
    int p=0;
    for(int i=1;p<=n;i+=2) p=p+i;
```

I know the time complexity for the above code if **i** were to increment by 1 then the time complexity would be approximately √n.

```
when i=1 -> p=0+1
i=2 -> p=1+2
i=3 -> p=1+2+3
i=4 -> p=1+2+3+4
i=k -> p=1+2+3+4+.....k
```

Since the loop is not dependent on **i** so it won't be **n** times. 
When p becomes greater than the loop will be terminated, therefore:

```
p>n
Since p=k(k+1)/2
k(k+1)/2>n
This expression can be written as
k^2=n (approximate)
k=√n
```

Please help me understand the complexity of the above code, when i is incremented by 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same as you did before:

```
i=1 -> p=0+1
i=2 -> p=0+1+3
i=3 -> p=0+1+3+5
...
```

So you add up every odd number. This is approximately (depending on whether you have an odd or even n) `n^2/4`

So you look for a `k` s.t. `k^2/4 > n`.
Since you increase i by two in each iteration, `k` equals two times the number of iteration but for the big O notation this does not really matter so you get again `O(√n)`.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Will it did not become the arithmetic series e.g: 0+2+4+6+8+...... equals to 
***k(k1+kn)/2***. Here k0 represents the first number of the series and kn represents the last number. So, In this problem , I ended up like this ***k(k1+kn)/2 >n***. But your comment makes sense to me.

Comment: I don't think so. You start with i=1 and then increase it by 2